# Searching words in R

Tags: r

In R I have descriptions in a column and I am searching for specific words in the description. For example:

```
id description
1 "this is a house"
2 "the house is white"
3 "the apartment is far"
4 "the house is close"
```

I want to know which descriptions contain the word "house", and I want to know which id's belong to them. I tried to use grepl but I did not succeed.

Can anyone help me? Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried that did not work?

Comment: Show what you tried with `grepl`. What went wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You can use functions that can use regular expressions matching, eg `grepl`:

```
df <- data.frame(id = 1:7,  description = c("this is a house", "the house is white", 
"the apartment is far", "the house is close", "House in the woods", "HOUSE", "Penthouse"))
df$id[grepl('(^| )house( |$|\\.)', tolower(df$description))]                 

#[1] 1 2 4 5 6
```

Adjust the regular expression depending on what you want to match. Here (^| ) matches beginning of a line or space and ( |$|\\.) space, end of line or comma.

Answer (score -1):

```
 grep("house",dat$description)
[1] 1 2 4
```

Comment: You should avoid code only comments. Please add a few lines of explanation to help current and future users understand your answer.